Talking about the past with present tense
I noticed that when natives recount stories and talk about the past for long periods of time they generally start using the present tense a lot. Because I don't really "feel" the tenses in French, they kind of just exist in a purely grammatical abstraction in my head, I generally don't notice until after they've switched to present for a bit. I was just then wondering, what would be a natural way to shift from past tense to present? For example, if I was telling someone the paragraph below, would there be an instance where it would be natural to start recounting in the present tense? (Feel free to of course pick apart any irrelevant mistakes I'll make when hastily typing it up!)
Céline, tu peux deviner qui j'ai vu hier dans la piscine? C'était Marc! Je savais pas qu'il a pu se remettre de sa chirurgie aussi rapidement. Naturellement, j'ai tenté de lui en parler après quelques tours et il m'a dit qu'en fait le médecin lui a déjà dit que son dos est en meilleure forme qu'avant l'accident. Marc m'a aussi dit qu'il a décidé de changer de travail et qu'il a trouvé un autre employeur qui allait mettre beaucoup plus d'accent sur la santé des ouvriers au travail. Je sais pas s'il voulait porter plainte contre son dernier employeur mais si ça advenait, Céline je pense qu'il serait important qu'on fasse plus d'efforts pour le soutenir. Tu sais qu'on a un peu disparu pendant sa guérison parce qu'on pensait que ce aurait été mieux de laisser Marc tranquille mais hier il m'a aussi exprimé que notre soutien lui avait manqué et que notre préscence le perturbera jamais.

Isn't it the same as in English, to cut to action, to make a story more vivd and immersive? ("Yesterday Marc was around the swimming pool [...] All of a sudden, he dives right in and I'm like - this guy is in perfect shape")

I don't think there is a need to change the text above, for naturalness or otherwise. There are a few small issues here and there, but that's about it.

It's all about style. You can switch to the present as early as the 3rd sentence: Naturellement, je tente [...]; even to the direct discourse when reporting what Marc said: [...] il me dit: "en fait le médecin m'a dit que mon dos {est | était} déjà en meilleure forme" etc.

You just have to get used to the tenses. The only real issue in French compared to English is that there is no present prefect. Generally, one wouldn't use the present throughout telling someone something as you did in your text, whether in English or French unless you are a writer using historical present.

It's exactly the same in English, any tips for English in this case can apply to French: Present verb forms referring to the past, Historical present, ...

@None in a way it is the same: the existence and use cases of the narrative present. However, English tenses are not in 1-to-1 correspondence with the French ones and I, for one, s/times turn to a past form when translating verbs to English. So there may be s/th for fr.SE here.

One area without overlap is encyclopedia biographies... For some reason, if you open a book of the kind that has a summary of the author's life events it can be in present tense ("1888. Born in Oxford. 1897. Family moves to Ireland."), but if this appeared in an encyclopedia article it would feel very odd ("In 1888 he is born in Oxford, and in 1897 his family moves to Ireland.") — as though it were describing the plot of a novel. Meanwhile this seems to be the default in French, such that reading articles on historical figures on French Wikipedia is very disorienting for Anglophones.

...For a ready-to-hand example, compare the tenses in the early life sections of the English and French articles on Barack Obama. Journalism too (which I see mentioned in the Wikipedia article None linked to) would avoid the present tense in English, except perhaps for a table of events similar to the author's life summary in a book.

Typically the second sentence (starting at Naturellement) could use present tense to make it more vivid:

... Je savais pas qu'il a pu se remettre de sa chirurgie aussi rapidement. Écoute : j'essaie de lui en parler après quelques tours et il me dit qu'en fait le médecin lui a déjà dit que son dos était en meilleure forme qu'avant l'accident. Marc me dit aussi qu'il a décidé de changer de travail et qu'il a trouvé un autre employeur qui va mettre beaucoup plus l'accent sur la santé des ouvriers au travail.

Here the goal would be to allow Celine to imagine the scene as if she had been present or if she could see a film of it.
The following sentence should use present tense, because the speaker does not know is Marc currently wants to go to a legal action or not:

Je sais pas s'il veut porter plainte contre son dernier employeur mais s'il le fait, Céline je pense qu'il serait important qu'on fasse plus d'efforts pour le soutenir.


I have replaced some wordings because I really feel that tenter and advenir are not that common when speaking but are more used in written language.

In English, it's called the present historical, and supposedly it’s only in writing, though honestly it’s often spoken in normal everyday casual speech.    A time indicator is needed, and then the present tense sounds normal & natural.
Your question —> If I was telling someone the paragraph below, would there be an instance where it would be natural to start recounting in the present tense?
My answer —> In your first sentence, you have the time indicator hier, so absolutely starting from the first sentence, present tense is possible.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Who says it's only in writing in English? I'm pretty sure that it's heard more often in speech.

@Peter Shor  There are many who agree with what Lambie has said, “Generally, one wouldn't use the present throughout telling someone something as you did in your text, whether in English or French unless you are a writer using historical present.”   And I said, “honestly it’s often spoken in normal everyday casual speech.”  And you said,  “I'm pretty sure that it's heard more often in speech.”   Yep, I agree, it’s not only in writing.

@G Diamond: You're right ... you need a time indicator. I was arguing with the statement "supposedly, it's only in writing," which you also seem to disagree with. So we're in agreement.
